# Python Networkx to R igraph conversion with errors

Tags: python, r, igraph, networkx

I am attempting to translate the following Python code (for `Networkx`) into R (for `igraph`).

```
# Python code

import csv
import networkx as nx
import urllib

DG=nx.DiGraph()

dogcsv=csv.DictReader(open("dogs.csv","rU"))

dogid=0

nodeStr=['id', 'species',   'Location 1', 'Location 2']

nodeInt=['sumflu']

fluCols=['Influenza-1', 'Influenza-2', 'Influenza-3', 'Influenza-4',
'Influenza-5', 'Influenza-6', 'Influenza-7', 'Influenza-8', 'Influenza-9']

for flu in fluCols:
    DG.add_node(flu,typ="species")

for row in dogcsv:
    dogID='animal'+str(dogid)
    DG.add_node(dogID,typ='animal')
    for dog in nodeStr:
        DG.node[dogID][dog]=row[dog]
    for dog in nodeInt:
        DG.node[dogID][dog]=int(row[dog])
    for flu in fluCols:
        if str(row[flu])=='1':
            DG.add_edge(dogID,flu)
    dogid=dogid+1
```

---

The following is my attempt at a partial conversion of from Python to R.

```
# R code

library("data.table")
library("igraph")

dogs <- make_empty_graph()

dogcsv <- fread("dogs.csv")

dogid <- 0

nodeStr <- c("id", "species", "Location 1", "Location 2")

nodeInt <- "sumflu"

fluCols <- c("Influenza-1", "Influenza-2", "Influenza-3", "Influenza-4", 
"Influenza-5", "Influenza-6", "Influenza-7", "Influenza-8")

for(flu in fluCols) {
dogs[flu] <- dogs %>% add_vertices(8) %>% add_vertices(dogs[flu], typ = "host")
    }
```

This is the error code that I receive when I run the last portion of R code:

```
Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  no 'dimnames[[.]]': cannot use character indexing
```

In Python `Networkx`, the graph can be called out by graphname.function (ex. `DG.add_node(dogID,typ='animal')`).

Is there an equivalent in R's `igraph`?

Is there any way to call out the nodes in R's `igraph` without having to define the number of nodes?

Also, will you offer hints or suggestions on completing the translation to R?

Thank you.

---

The following contains the .csv data:

id,species,Location 1,Location 2,animal id,sumvirus,Influenza-1,Influenza-2,Influenza-3,Influenza-4,Influenza-5,Influenza-6,Influenza-7,Influenza-8,Influenza-9
YUI-4322,host1,Park 4,Park,MW 391,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-4321,host2,Park 4,Park,MW 390,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-4320,host2,Park 4,Park,MW 389,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-4319,host2,Park 4,Park,MW 388,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-7318,host2,Park 4,Park,MW 387,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-4317,host1,Park 4,Park,MW 386,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-4316,host2,Park 4,Park,MW 385,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
YUI-2315,host1,Shelter 2,Shelter,MV319,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
YUI-4314,host1,Shelter 2,Shelter,MV 332,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0

Comment: You may be interested in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433402/r-igraph-rename-vertices](this). There exists an igraph Python version; perhaps as an intermediate step you could translate into that. Though how could you leave networkx? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused with what you are doing, but I can tell you that dogs is a graph object, and you are trying to do multiple things in a line that don't make sense together.

Calling dogs[flu] gives all vertices connected to flu.

add_vertices(8) is adding 8 new vertices to the graph.

add_vertices(dogs[flu], typ="host") is adding the same nodes into the graph that would already exist if dogs[flu] is callable.

Just add the nodes all before (add_vertices[fluCols], although it may need ints instead of strings) and then modify those nodes after.